# How to randomly pick four elements from an array without repeating in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, random

Let's say:

```
String[] fruitsArray = new String[] {"apple", "orange", "pear", "banana", "cherry", "blueberry", "papaya", "litchi"};
```

How to randomly pick four elements from this array without repeating?

Example result would be `["orange", "pear","blueberry","litchi"]`
while result like `["apple", "orange","orange","papaya"]` is not acceptable.

Comment: either pick again if your randomly picked element is already present in the output or remove picked elements from the `fruitsArray`.

Comment: Is the original `fruitsArray` supposed to be immutable, or are solutions that rearrange or delete elements considered acceptable?

Answer (score 5):

Generation of non-repeatable numbers is not an easy task compared to a simple shuffling the array or a collection using [`Collections::shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-).

```
final String[] fruitArray = new String[]{"apple", "orange", "pear", "banana",
                                         "cherry", "blueberry", "papaya", "litchi"};

// SHUFFLE
final List<String> fruitList = Arrays.asList(fruitArray);
Collections.shuffle(fruitList);

// TEST IT
fruitList.stream()
         .limit(4)                      // sets the count to 4
         .forEach(System.out::println); // prints qualified random items without repetition
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Random() object in java.

Below is an example of getting 3 random elements from an ArrayList hope this help you.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList; 
 import java.util.List; 
 import java.util.Random; 

 public class GFG { 

// Drive Function 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 

    // create a list of Integer type 
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
    // add 5 element in ArrayList 
    list.add(10); 
    list.add(20); 
    list.add(30); 
    list.add(40); 
    list.add(50); 

    GFG obj = new GFG(); 

    // boundIndex for select in sub list 
    int numberOfElements = 3; 

    // take a random element from list and print them 
    System.out.println(obj.getRandomElement(list, 
                                 numberOfElements)); 
} 

// Function select an element base on index and return 
// an element 
public List<Integer> getRandomElement(List<Integer> list, 
                                      int totalItems) 
{ 
    Random rand = new Random(); 

    // create a temporary list for storing 
    // selected element 
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) { 

        // take a raundom index between 0 to size  
        // of given List 
        int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(list.size()); 

        // add element in temporary list 
        newList.add(list.get(randomIndex)); 

        // Remove selected element from orginal list 
        list.remove(randomIndex); 
    } 
    return newList; 
} 
}
```

Output:

```
  [50, 40, 30]
```

Comment: In your example there is nothing to prevent duplicate values

Comment: Oh! My mistake..  Modified the code for remove repetitions

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of random integers and use them as index for the array

```
int[] indexes = new Random().ints(4, 0, fruitsArray.length).toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(fruitsArray[i]);
}
```